# Automate play store release with Managed publishing - Google Play API

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-bundle, android-developer-api

I want to deploy and publish multiple at the same time. Currently I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/deploy-aab-google-play npm library to push bundle files. It is working well doing the job for me.

But, I have a new requirement. I need to get all apps approved before going live. Play stores "Managed Publishing" is very good option to do so, but it is not possible to publish every app manually from play console dashboard like shown in below image. I need to deploy more than 30 apps (increasing day by day) at once.
[Play store Managed publishing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MzsT.png)

Can we get app status through API call or any npm library which return `is app approved and ready to publish` and if so make app through API call or any npm library only.

Any tools such as `deploy-aab-google-play` which i use to push aab files.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Did you find a way to do that? And also how you publish an app when is its 'ready to publish' status?

Comment: @FerhatErgün Not yet.  To publish 'ready to publish' apps we need to go publishing overview on play console and make it live from there.